# Intercept, b1 and b2 of a plot made with effect package

Tags: r, plot, effect, lme4

I am using the Effect package to prepare the data of a model in order to plot the fixed effects.

My data is

```
Fecha   Departamento    Zona    Rendimiento
2006         1            10    7.700
2007         1            10    9.900
2008         1            10    7.900
2009         1            10    5.000
2010         1            10    8.500
2011         1            10    7.245
2012         1            10    5.500
2013         1            10    9.000
2014         1            10    7.400
2015         1            10    8.900
2016         1            10    8.700
2006         2             9    7.500
2007         2             9    9.500
2008         2             9    7.400
2009         2             9    5.000
2010         2             9    9.000
2011         2             9    6.935
2012         2             9    6.300
2013         2             9    8.500
2014         2             9    7.800
2015         2             9    9.000
2016         2             9    10.400
```

I prepared all the variables and packages

```
summary(Maiz1)
Maiz1$Zona<-as.factor(Maiz1$Zona)
Maiz1$Departamento<-as.factor(Maiz1$Departamento)
summary(Maiz1)
str(Maiz1)
na.omit(Maiz1)

library(lattice)
library(Matrix)
library("lme4")
library(nlme)
library (effects)
```

Then I used a lme model to analyze the data and create the residual column.

```
mod<-lme(Rendimiento~1+Zona+Fecha+Zona:Fecha,random=list(Departamento=pdIdent(~1)),
              data=Maiz1,method="REML",control=lmeControl(niterEM=150,
              msMaxIter=200),na.action=na.omit,keep.data=FALSE)
summary(mod)
anova(mod)

Maiz1$Residuos<-with(Maiz1, residuals(mod))
```

The best model for my data is the cuadratic, so I made it.

```
cuadratic<-lme(Rendimiento~1+(poly(Fecha,2,raw=TRUE))+Zona+(1+(poly(Fecha,2,raw=TRUE)):Zona) 
             ,random=list(Departamento=pdIdent(~1))
             ,method="REML"
             ,control=lmeControl(niterEM=150
             ,msMaxIter=200)
             ,na.action=na.omit
             ,data=Maiz1
             ,keep.data=FALSE)
summary(cuadratic)
anova(cuadratic)
```

In order to obtain plots of the model with all the effects and others plots with only some effects I used the *Effect package*.

```
effcua<-Effect(c("Fecha","Zona"),cuadratic, partial.residuals=TRUE)
summary(effcua)
mz<-as.data.frame(effcua)

plot(effcua, lines=list(multiline=FALSE, col=c("black"), lwd=2),  
     partial.residuals=list(col=c("gray"), cex=(0.2)), 
     confint=list(alpha=c(0)),
     axes=list(y=list(lim={c(0, 12000)})),
     main="Maíz")

effcuac<-Effect(c("Fecha"),cuadratic, 
                partial.residuals=TRUE)
summary(effcuac)
maiz1<-as.data.frame(effcuac)

plot(effcuac, lines=list(multiline=FALSE, col=c("black"), lwd=2),  
     partial.residuals=list(col=c("gray"), cex=(0.2)), 
     confint=list(alpha=c(0)),
     axes=list(y=list(lim={c(0, 12000)})),
     main="Maíz")
```

So I want to know how can I get the *Intercept, b1 and b2* that R used to plot the second plot, in this case with only the *Fecha* effect.